# Вывод значений из массива нечётных чисел

Tags: массивы, java

**Задача:**

> Создайте массив из всех нечётных чисел от 1 до 99, выведите его на
> экран в строку, а затем этот же массив выведите на экран тоже в
> строку, но в обратном порядке (99 97 95 93 … 7 5 3 1).

**Мой код:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //чтобы узнать размер массива, вычислим его циклом
        int count = 0; //индекс массива
        int n = 1; //значение индекса массива
        while (n < 99) { //на выходе из этого цикла имеем count когда в него записано 99
            count++;
            n = n + 2;
        }
        System.out.println(count + " " + n); //находим что значение 99 можно записать в 49 ячейку
        int[] massiv = new int[count]; //объявляем массив
        int number = 1; //начальное значение ячейки с индексом 0
        for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
            massiv[i] = number;
            System.out.print(massiv[i] + " ");
            number = number + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе имеем такой **результат**:

> 49 99
>
> 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97

Куда пропадает значение 99?

Comment: аццкий код, я думаю потому, что i < massiv.length должно быть <=

Comment: while (n < 99) - вот здесь Вы 99 и потеряли

Comment: Про отладку слышали? Или выводите в лог/консоль значения (в вашем случае n, в странном и ненужном цикле для вычисления длинны массива) и думайте, почему они куда-то, как вы выразились, пропадают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int max = 99;
int result[] = new int[ (int)( max / 2.0 + 0.6 ) ];
for ( int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    result[i] = i * 2 + 1;
System.out.println( result.length );
System.out.println( result[ result.length -1 ] );
```

А ответ, как это ни покажется Вам удивительным, в том, что элементов должно быть 50 для того, чтобы вместился 99. Утверждение, что `находим что значение 99 можно записать в 49 ячейку` неверно.

Comment: Количество нечетных а диапазоне от Low до Up (включительно, Low и Up нечетные) будет

    (Up - Low) / 2 + 1;

Comment: @avp, спасибо. Я предложил скажем так «кроссязычный» вариант инициализации массива, потому что не знаю точно, как поведет себя java разделив int на int- не уверен, что она вернет- int или float.

Comment: @avp: и вообще количество чисел в промежутке `[a, b]`, имеющих остаток `r` по модулю `m` равно 

    floor((b - r) / m) - floor((a - 1 + r) / m)

(деление с плавающей точкой!)

Comment: а почему элементов должно быть 50, если на 50 элементе значение уже 101?

Comment: @elite_kr, счет начинается с нуля, а не единицы- в школе обманывали :)  
Далее, сколько элементов в множестве [1;3;5] ? (5-1)/2+1 Аналогично можно найти количество элементов [1;3...97;99], чуть выше формула общего случая в комментарии @VladD.

Comment: Вообще в Java целые они еще и двоичные во внутреннем представлении (также, как и в C/C++ и большинстве других языков). 

Поэтому работающая формула для диапазона (включительного):

    if (low > high) {
 int t = low;
 low = high;
 high = t;
    }
    int oddnum = ((high - (low | 1)) / 2) + ((high == low && (low & 1) == 0) ? 0 : 1);

независимо от знака low и high.

Comment: @avp: моя формула должна покатить для любого знака тоже. Для `b < a` она может дать отрицательный результат, правда. (Да, это самореклама.)

Comment: @VladD, понятно, что Ваша работает. Просто как-то странно использовать плавающую арифметику для подсчета количества нечетных в диапазоне. 

Ведь интуитивно ясно, что их там примерно полдиапазона.

Хотя, я вовсе не утверждаю, что Ваша медленнее, а моя понятней.

Comment: @avp: деление с плавающей точкой нужно лишь для округления вниз. (Обычное деление округляет в сторону нуля, что для отрицательных чисел не одно и то же.) Если есть быстрый способ делить с округлением вниз в языке _X_, нужно использовать именно его. Ну или если числа гарантированно положительные, можно использовать обычное деление.

Comment: Вообще говоря, должно быть `(int)(max / 2.0 + 0.6)`. Текущий вариант приводит к ошибке компиляции из-за того, что к `int` приводится `max`, а не результат выражения.

Comment: @regent спасибо за замечание. В ближайшее время исправлю этот ответ.

Answer (score 1):

если порядок операций важен, можно сделать так

```
int i = 1;
int max = 99;
int count = -1;
int [] arr = new int[max%2==0 ? max/2 : max/2+1];

//  забиваем массив, выводим элемент
while(i <= 99)
{
    arr[++count] = i;
    System.out.print(i +" ");
    i += 2;
}

//  
System.out.println();

//  выводим элементы в обратном порядке
for(int j=arr.length-1; j>=0; j--)
{
    System.out.print(arr[j] +" ");
}
```

но в реальном мире время дороже чем место

```
int min = 1,
    max = 99,
    count = -1;
int [] arr = new int[max%2==0 ? max/2 : max/2+1];
//  
String strSorted = "",
       strReversed = "";

//
while(count < arr.length-1)
{
    arr[++count] = min;
    strSorted += min +" ";
    strReversed = min +" "+ strReversed;
    min += 2;
}
System.out.println(strSorted);
System.out.println(strReversed);
```

Comment: @qpaycm, интуиция мне подсказывает, что в "реальном" мире (с учетом буферизации вывода и неэффективной конкатенации в Java (хотя бы StringBuffer для этого взяли)) для большого `max` первый вариант выигрывает не только по месту, но и по времени.

Comment: @avp, судя по всему интуиция вас подвела. Подводя простой подсчет сложности(time complexity) вы сравниваете O(n^2) с O(n). Касательно StringBuffer впервые слышу и с интересом ознакомлюсь.

Comment: @qpaycm, а где Вы *квадрат* увидели?

В первом варианте 2 прохода по нечетным (O(n)), а во втором один (те же O(n)), только коэффициент при этом O(n) из-за построения строк поболее выйдет.

Кстати, при тривиальной реализации String (тело строки занимает непрерывный участок памяти) этот коэффициент сам будет стремиться к квадрату `count`.

Comment: @avp, пардоньте, протер глаза, собрал мозги и вижу, 2n против n - это O(n) всё верно. Тем не менее, даже если String - это массив объектов(что удивительно) и тело строки занимает непрерывный участок памяти тогда как StringBuffer/StringBuilder - это скорее связанные списки объектов и всё-же, второй вариант быстрее!! http://pastebin.com/fW1xTCee но Вы правы, StringBuffer лучше, а StringBuilder ещё быстрее лучшего.

Comment: @qpaycm, да, подзабыл я Java. К PrintStream (т.е. System.out) буфер не подключается. 

Поэтому собственная буферизация (построение всего вывода в String/StringBuffer/StringBuilder) дает существенный выигрыш.

Кстати, учтите, что самый быстрый для циклов StringBuilder - not synchronized (впрочем, для однопоточных программ это не важно).

Comment: @avp, учту.

Answer (score 0):

```
package my.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayTest {
    public static final int MIN=1;
    public static final int MAX=100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List oddList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=MIN;i<MAX;i+=2){
            oddList.add(i);
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        Integer[] oddNumbers = new Integer [oddList.size()];
        oddList.toArray(oddNumbers);
        for(int i=oddNumbers.length-1;i>=0 ;i--){
            System.out.print(oddNumbers[i]+ " ");
        }
   }
}
```

Хотя это не совсем буквально вып задание. но мне так проще..

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мой вариант ущербнее?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr;
    arr = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            arr[i] = i;
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int i = 100 - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1]) {
                int tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
        if (a < 50) {
            System.out.print(arr[a] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Конечно, он громоздкий, зато все работает.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вот так сходу я готов назвать "ущербными" `if (i % 2 == 1)` (почему бы просто не сделать `for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2)`?) и `if (a < 50)` (почему бы просто не сделать `for (int a = 0; a < 50; a++)`?). Саму идею решения обсуждать не буду.

Comment: и впрямь, спасибо за совет. Буду учиться!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String []args){

    int arr[]= new int[100];
    for (int i=1; i<100; i+=2){
        arr[i]=i;
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");}
    System.out.println();
    for (int i=99; i>0; i-=2){
        arr[i]=i;
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] bar = new byte[50];
for (byte i = 0; i < 50; i++) System.out.print((bar[i] = (byte) (i*2 + 1)) + " ");
System.out.println("");
for (byte i = 49; i >= 0; i--) System.out.print(bar[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[] = new int[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = (i + 1) + i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
```